# How did this user get 16 different and unrelated badges on the same day?

Tags: discussion, badges, users, activity-tab

I was looking at the late earners of the [Caucus badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus), when I noticed that way after the election closed (17 hours after), [bimal george](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4324242/bimal-george?tab=activity) earned the badge.

So I went to their profile, and I discovered that 15 other badges (all bronze but 1 silver) they'd earned on the same day. 9 of them (including Caucus) were earned at the same second of the day, and the rest were earned minutes later, minutes apart.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Badges are awarded in batches, so it's not unexpected or unusual that they would allow show up as earned at the same time. It's also not unexpected that someone would complete all of the basic site-usage tasks required to earn bronze badges all in one day.

Comment: Certainly not. _But,_ that doesn't explain why the first 9 badges where gotten at the same instant. Also, the user is not new, and has posted and commented before. They have 195 rep.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's a pretty weak duplicate.  The answer to which you're mapping as duplicate isn't even an answer; it is a comment, and the question is essentially unrelated to this one.

Comment: True, but don't you think it _was_ probably because another account was merged in? (I'd have appreciated that said in a comment or answer though, instead of _just_ closing it as a dupe).

Comment: Yup, it was another user that was merged in. Sorry, thought that the duplicate was clear. Updated the dupe list.